# Disable tab in a TTabSet in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to disable (but not entirely remove) a single tab from a TTabSet? How?

It doesn't appear that there's an obvious way to do this.

Comment: How do you want to disable? Do you mean it does nothing if you click on that tab, or the contents of that tab are inoperable when you select it? If the former, I'm thinking do an OnClick event and have it do nothing if the disabled tab is being clicked.

Comment: ideally, label for the tab in a disabled font color, and nothing happens when you click on the disabled tab.

Comment: Use the TabSet's OnChange event.  The 2nd parameter (NewTab) is the index of the Newly Selected Tab and the 3rd parameter (AllowChange) is a boolean field you can set to either allow (set to true) or disallow (set to false) changing to the new tab.  i.e. AllowChange := NewTab <> 1;  Allows any tab but the second tab to be selected

Comment: have a look at one of my earlier questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456039/pagecontrol-disabled-text-on-tabs-gray-text to show the tab in a nice "disabled font colour" and follow @user582118 advice about the OnChange event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change the color of the label to a disabled font color you have to override the drawing of the tabs by changing it's Style property to tsOwnerDraw. Once you've done that you can use the OnDrawTab Event, for example like this :

```
var
indexOfDisabledTab : Byte = 1;

procedure TForm1.TabSet1DrawTab(Sender: TObject; TabCanvas: TCanvas; R: TRect;
  Index: Integer; Selected: Boolean);
var S : String;
begin

   if IndexOfDisabledTab = Index
   then
     TabCanvas.Font.Color := clGray
   else
     TabCanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;

  S := TabSet1.Tabs.Strings[Index];
  TabCanvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfVerticalCenter,tfSingleLine]);

end;
```

To prevent the user from clicking the tab you can use the TTabSet OnChange Event like this:

```
procedure TForm1.TabSet1Change(Sender: TObject; NewTab: Integer;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin

 AllowChange := not (NewTab = IndexOfDisabledTab);

end;
```

Comment: While the general idea seems to work that you have here, the text isn't centered vertically anymore so it looks a bit off. Is there an easy way to fix that?

Comment: ahh, I found the answer to my own question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653632/why-dont-tfverticalcenter-and-tfbottom-work-as-expected-in-tcanvas-textrect) Just have to set some TTextFormat parameters instead of an empty array as a parameter to TextRect

Comment: You can edit Peter's answer, that would be helpful for future users, I think and better than the `(R,S, [] )`